# I can read out in my Blazor server app, the selected item of a select box. Is it also possible to read out the index number of the selected item?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, blazor, blazor-server-side, selecteditem

With my code below I can read out the selected item in my select box (@selected_type). Is it also possible to read out something like a index number of the selected item? With index number I mean is it the first, second , third option value, of the total option values in the select list. Is that possible?

```
<td class="td_DiagBuff_data" max-width="150">
    <select value="@selected_type" @onchange="@(e => { func_MD_type(e,index);  })">
        <option value="">--------</option>
        <option value="">NC-Machine Data</option>
        <option value="">CH-Machine Data</option>
        <option value="">AX-Machine Data</option>
        <option value="">DR-Machine Data</option>
        <option value="">SD-Machine Data</option>
        <option value="">R-Parameter</option>
        <option value="">GUD</option>

    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Not sure if you can find the index directly, but if you make the values a collection in code, then when the `onchange` event fires, you can work out the index from the selected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I need to do this I move my `<options>` into a collection or dictionary of `KeyValuePair` with a unique identifier (If using a dictionary then `Key` should be the unique field).

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _machineDataList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(string.Empty, "--------"), // String.Empty will force required validation attribute.
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("0", "NC-Machine Data"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "CH-Machine Data"),
    .
    .
    .

};
```

Your markup becomes

```
<select @bind="selected_type">
    @foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> pair in _machineDataList)
    {
        <option value="@pair.Key">@pair.Value</option>
    }
</select>
```

And access the selections like this

```
var selection = _machineDataList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key== selected_type);
```