# In my Blazor server app I have a razor page with a combobox. How can I read out the index (raw) number of the selected item of the combobox?

Tags: combobox, blazor-server-side, razor-pages, selecteditem

In my Blazor server app I have a razor page with a combobox. How can I read out the index (raw) number of the selected item of the combobox?

For example "select" is the index=0, opel index=1,ford index=2.... If the user selects ford I want to read out the index value "2"

```
<td class="td_DiagBuff_data" max-width="150">
<select value="@selected_type" @onchange="@(e => { func_MD_type(e,index);  })">
    <option>select</option>
    <option>opel</option>
    <option>ford</option>
    <option>subaru</option>
    <option>renault</option>
    <option>mercedes</option>    

</select>
</td>
```

Comment: Put the options data in an array, then populate the select from that, and then get the index of the selected item in your onchange handler.

Comment: I hope this is what your looking for [Selected Index in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73828622/i-can-read-out-in-my-blazor-server-app-the-selected-item-of-a-select-box-is-it)

Comment: Yes absolutely, thanks a lot